# The "same old" dy/dx question? Separation of differentials?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics, epsilon-delta, classical-mechanics

I completely understand this question has been addressed one too many times. But I still simply cannot wrap my head around the concept of dy/dx.

Simply put, when can we treat dy/dx as a ratio and when can we not in physics? I have been time and again told dy/dx is NOT a ratio but a limit of a difference quotient, if that be the case, I keep seeing classical mechanics authors indiscriminately treat it like a fraction!

For instance, I have just recently seen this:

Given position vector r(t), where r(t) = sin(t) i + cos(t) j (i and j are unit vectors along x and y axis.

Then I suddenly see that dr(t) = (cot(t) i - sin(t) j) dt. How? Why? What? I have made such computations when I was in high-school, but I never thought about such things. But now that I am, I find it most disconcerting.

How is this working? This is in context of the line integral with regards to work done. The author here is discussing the line integral of f.ds

Also, how can we ever take the dot product of an infinitesimal with the force. The **ds**, after all, and in the Riemann integral sense, is just a delimiter, and otherwise has no other computational value. I have been told that that it is USEFUL to view ds as an infinitesimal breadth, but I don't want to do things because they are a means to an end, I want to fully understand the means, no matter how trivial.

I really, really, want to understand the truth of dy/dx, so that I may be able to use the tool to 'build' and 'craft' some mathematics. But as of now, I am just using the tool without any insight.

Comment: What you suddenly see is 100% wrong. $r’(t)$ is the derivative.

Comment: Even this must have been mentioned a zillion of times: treat them as fractions and don't (***don't!***) forget to check the results. Physics is as we know an experimental science.

Comment: In standard calculus and analysis, rigorously speaking, as you know $dy/dx$ is not a ratio, but *notation* for a limit of difference quotients. However, there are instances where manipulating it as if it were a ratio provide a convenient short-cut to correct computations, provided we are careful. It is often easier to learn these sorts of recipes first, in an intro ODE or calc class--somewhat mechanically--before we understand what is truly going on under the hood, by looking at advance calculus or real analysis textbooks. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, I don't understand. They take the derivative on both sides, and then they multiply "dt" on both sides.

Comment: When physicists say things like $dy = f'(x) dx$, you can interpret it like this: $dx$ is a tiny but finite real number, $dy$ is the amount that $f$ changes when its input changes from $x$ to $x + dx$, and they really meant to write $dy \approx f'(x) dx$. Now everything is fine.

Comment: @littleO I understand this, thank you. But, and it is a big but, I am unable to understand what is TRULY going on, and if I don't then I may never be able to truly command this tool of calculus/analysis.

Comment: But that is exactly what is going on. This is how to make sense of the physicist’s intuition (which is also a mathematician’s intuition). If $dx$ is a tiny but finite real number and $dy$ is the change in $f$ when its input changes from $x$ to $x+ dx$ then it really is true that $dy \approx f’(x) dx$. Now we can manipulate $dx$ and $dy$ the same way we’d manipulate any real numbers. It is true that any equations we then obtain are only approximate. But, we can hope at the end to obtain an exactly true equation (not just an approximation) by taking a limit as $dx$ approaches $0$.

Comment: In short (I know next week we'll see that SAMO question here again): Non-standard analysis has been invented by people who wanted to know what is TRULY going on. Ditto: differential forms. Please google and learn patiently. See you in a year or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came in to discuss and unrelated problem hours ago in this site and N hours after i'm still here. But saw your question come in and I actually find this enchanting (sorry it got down voted).
But I wanted to share some of my thinking in this area, and maybe we can give a different perspective to this issue that's so mentioned in physics education!

Anyway, I think what physics textbooks should actually cover is the idea of "implicit differentiation", see https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/implicit-differentiation.html .
It is correct to say that $dy/dx$ is not a fraction, it is a guide telling us what limits we are looking at.
And it just so happens that when we have comparable "guides" then this syntax does look a tad like a fraction.

A simplified version of your example, if $r = r(t) = \sin t$, then
$$
\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \sin t = \cos t \frac{dt}{dt} = \cos{t}
$$
However, if we looked at it as an exercise of implicit differentiation the above could be seen as
$$
dr = \cos{t} dt
$$

Which comes into play because then you can do line integrals properly as the above inside an integral would be seen as
$$
\int dr = r = \int \cos (t) dt = \sin{t} + C
$$

Note how the first integral is now being done along $r$, which allows us to solve $\int dx = x + c$, instead of being puzzled over how $r$ depends on some other variables.

---

tl;dr knowing that implicit differentiation is mathematically valid and about doing integrals with the simplest set of variables I think is what physics textbooks should talk about instead of giving us a riddle about something not being some other thing without telling us what it actually is (implicit differentiation, at least most of the time).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't fully understand. In all the implicit differentiation that I have done, one does not treat dy/dx as a fraction. In other words, I am not able to understand how is 
dr = cos(t)dt, I only know that dr/dt = cost(t), and dr/dt is NOT a fraction, that you may cross multiply.

Comment: I'm going to try to focus on the specifics of your comment to make sure I'm misunderstanding.
You said "I am not able to understand how is dr = cos(t)dt", to follow that logic, please check out the link I shared on "implicit differentiation", and maybe look for a couple other examples. When I was learning it I had to read-it a couple times for it to sink it. But the mechanics behind that are what explain why "dr"s, "dx"s, etc can be moved around and how to interpret them.

Comment: Nowhere in the link does the author explain how they treat dx as a fraction. Any other links, please?

Comment: @S_M is not about treating dx as a fraction, they are not. The key is to understand how implicit differentiation works. The mechanics of implicit differentiation is why "dx"s, "dr"s appear in places and they seem to work out and allow things such as $dr = cos t dt$ to be written and then integrated.